# Jquery Click function only changes HTML once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Clicking the button changes the HTML but when i click on the button again it just reloads the already changed HTML. I want it to change the HTML again to something different (thats randomized).

(i have a JSON variable called 'list' with a bunch of quotes)

Why doesnt this over ride the last button click each time i press the button? I thought the function would basically repeat.

Javascript:

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".clickMe").on('click', function() {
   $("#quoteMsge").html(list[number].quote);  
   $("#author").html(list[number].by);
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<h1> Generate your quote! </h1>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2 id="quoteMsge"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
Generate a quote!</h2>
    <h3 id="author">- Me</h3>
    <div class="button">
      <button class="btn btn-primary clickMe">Gimme a Quote!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have been on this for hours but i am a noob so please forgive me. I have used the setInterval function which did work but didnt seem right? Is that viable?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Your code picks exactly 1 random number.

Comment: Once you set the value of the number variable it never changes.

Comment: As these comments point out, you need to change the value of `number` inside your click function - otherwise it will remain the same for every click, and will always print the same message.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".clickMe").on('click', function() {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
    $("#quoteMsge").html(list[number].quote);  
    $("#author").html(list[number].by);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating the random number only once, therefore on each click, the same number is being added.

Use this code:

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".clickMe").on('click', function() {
   number = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
   $("#quoteMsge").html(list[number].quote);  
   $("#author").html(list[number].by);
  });

});
```

Here is a snippet demonstrating it in action:

```js
var list = [{
  'quote': 'Quote 1',
  'by': 'Author 1',
}, {
  'quote': 'Quote 2',
  'by': 'Author 2',
}, {
  'quote': 'Quote 3',
  'by': 'Author 3',
}]

var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".clickMe").on('click', function() {
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
    $("#quoteMsge").html(list[number].quote);
    $("#author").html(list[number].by);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="clickMe" value="Click Me">

<div>Message:
  <p id="quoteMsge" style="display:inline-block"></p>
</div>

<div>Author:
  <p id="author" style="display:inline-block"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the creation of the random number in the event function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".clickMe").on('click', function() {
   var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
   $("#quoteMsge").html(list[number].quote);  
   $("#author").html(list[number].by);
 });
});
```